# How can I split my json file?

Tags: json

I am moving my dnd's character's sheet from excel to json.
I would love to keep my files kind of "small".

For example :

Can I write this json :

character.json

```
"{  
    "title":"Main",
    "header":{  
        "name":"",
        "player":"",
        "classes":[  
            {  
                "name":"",
                "level":0
            }
        ],
        "level":"",
        "speed":0
    },
    "abilities":{  
        "ability":{  
            "name":"",
            "permanent":{  
                "score":"",
                "modifier":""
            },
            "temporary":{  
                "score":"",
                "modifier":""
            }
        }
    },
    "damageReduction":0,
    "hitPoint":{  
        "total":0,
        "current":0
    },
    "initiative":0
}"
```

as :

character.json

```
"{  
    "title":"Main",
    "header": header.json, // or anything working I don't mind
    "abilities":{  
        "ability":{  
            "name":"",
            "permanent":{  
                "score":"",
                "modifier":""
            },
            "temporary":{  
                "score":"",
                "modifier":""
            }
        }
    },
    "damageReduction":0,
    "hitPoint":{  
        "total":0,
        "current":0
    },
    "initiative":0
}"
```

header.json

```
{  
    "name":"",
    "player":"",
    "classes":[  
        {  
            "name":"",
            "level":0
        }
     ],
    "level":"",
    "speed":0
}
```

I try "json link" and some others keyword on Google but I didn't find anything related. (I discovered [json-ld](http://json-ld.org/) and it's pretty nice but off-topic :) )

Edit :

If you think I should move my question somewhere else into SE ([programmers?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/)), please args about it on commnent.

Comment: Why? Why is having "small" files important? The strength of JSON is that you can encapsuate information about a single object. Also: What language, and what have you tried so far?

Comment: > Why is having "small" files important?

I find it easier to read and to manipulate.

> What language,

json? I am not sure I understand you correctly.

> and what have you tried so far? 

Looking into json's spec and google stuff to find a way to achieve this.

Comment: JSON isn't a language any more than a spreadsheet is a language. Separate files are fine, but you'll have to stick 'em together again.

Comment: I know it is a data format. This is why I didn't understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I'll start off by questioning what you're trying to accomplish. Why are you trying to split up a single logical object into separate elements?

But as JSON is a nested data structure, you can of course, split it up however you wish. E.g. if you want to separate out your 'header':

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON;
use Data::Dumper;

my $json_str = '{  
    "title":"Main",
    "header":{  
        "name":"",
        "player":"",
        "classes":[  
            {  
                "name":"",
                "level":0
            }
        ],
        "level":"",
        "speed":0
    },
    "abilities":{  
        "ability":{  
            "name":"",
            "permanent":{  
                "score":"",
                "modifier":""
            },
            "temporary":{  
                "score":"",
                "modifier":""
            }
        }
    },
    "damageReduction":0,
    "hitPoint":{  
        "total":0,
        "current":0
    },
    "initiative":0
}';

my $json = decode_json($json_str);

## split out the 'header' element:
my $header_str = to_json( $json->{header}, { pretty => 1 } );
print "HEADER:\n";
print $header_str;

## insert a filename into the 'main' element:
delete( $json->{header} );
$json->{header} = "somefile.json";

print "REST:\n";
my $rest_of_json = to_json( $json, { pretty => 1 } );
print $rest_of_json;
```

Comment: Thank you to take the time to answer. I want to split it to simplify the edition. We are a group of programmer who loves DnD and we are going to start edit it by hand. (Until one of us write a script to edit it). If you want to learn more about the topic check this [repo](https://github.com/Dall0o/DnDCharacterJSON/). Basically, I want to link `Skills.json` to `Character.json`. I am looking to stay language agnostic for now.